# View is not rerendered in Nested ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I have the following component that renders a grid of semi transparent characters:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(self.settings.numRows) x \(self.settings.numColumns)")
            ForEach(0..<self.settings.numRows){ i in
                Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(0..<self.settings.numColumns){ j in
                            Spacer()
                            // why do I get an error when I try to multiply i * j
                            self.getSymbol(index:j)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
```

`settings` is an EnvironmentObject

Whenever `settings` is updated the Text in the outermost `VStack` is correctly updated. However, the rest of the view is not updated (Grid has same dimenstions as before). Why is this?

Second question:
Why is it not possible to access the `i` in the inner `ForEach`-loop and pass it as a argument to the function?

I get an error at the outer `ForEach`-loop:

> Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Your ForEach needs `id: \.self` added after your range.

#### Explanation

ForEach has [several initializers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach). You are using

```
init(_ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)
```

where `data` **must** be a constant.

If your range may change (e.g. you are adding or removing items from an array, which will change the upper bound), then you need to use

```
init(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)
```

You supply a keypath to the `id` parameter, which uniquely identifies each element that `ForEach` loops over. In the case of a `Range<Int>`, the element you are looping over is an `Int` specifying the array index, which is unique. Therefore you can simply use the `\.self` keypath to have the ForEach identify each index element by its own value.

Here is what it looks like in practice:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var array = [1, 2, 3]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add") {
                self.array.append(self.array.last! + 1)
            }

            // this is the key part  v--------v
            ForEach(0..<array.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(index): \(self.array[index])")
                //Note: If you want more than one views here, you need a VStack or some container, or will throw errors
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run that, you'll see that as you press the button to add items to the array, they will appear in the `VStack` automatically. If you remove "`id: \.self`", you'll see your original error:

```
`ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. 
Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)`
and provide an explicit `id`!"
```

Comment: Good idea to construct an identifiable like this. I went all the way around in my solution (I updated my answer).

Comment: @Asadefa Without the context of the error, I can't tell what issue you're having. I suggest asking a new question with the code that's not working. In general terms, you are passing a closure as an argument, and the closure needs to return something (probably a `View`), but you aren't returning anything (the empty tuple `()` indicates the closure returns `Void`).

Comment: I tried to have two texts in, and it threw an error. I suggested an edit

Comment: If the ForEach loop is inside a Picker, one additional bit of magic is required, add .id(self.array) to the picker (update "array" to whatever your array is named ) as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903986/swiftui-foreach-in-picker-doesnt-update

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the problem that bothered for two days.

Answer (score 1):

ForEach should only be used for **constant** data. So it is only evaluated once by definition. Try wrapping it in a List and you will see errors being logged like:

> ForEach, Int, TupleView<(Spacer, HStack, Int, TupleView<(Spacer, Text, Spacer)>>>, Spacer)>> count (7) != its initial count (0). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

I was surprised by this as well, and unable to find any official documentation about this limitation.

As for why it is not possible for you to access the i in the inner ForEach-loop, I think you probably have a misleading compiler error on your hands, related to something else in the code that is missing in your snippets. It did compile for me after completing the missing parts with a best guess (Xcode 11.1, Mac OS 10.14.4).

Here is what I came up with to make your ForEach go over something Identifiable:

```
struct SettingsElement: Identifiable {
    var id: Int { value }

    let value: Int

    init(_ i: Int) { value = i }
}

class Settings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rows = [SettingsElement(0),SettingsElement(1),SettingsElement(2)]
    @Published var columns = [SettingsElement(0),SettingsElement(1),SettingsElement(2)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings

    func getSymbol(index: Int) -> Text { Text("\(index)") }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(self.settings.rows.count) x \(self.settings.columns.count)")
            ForEach(self.settings.rows) { i in
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(self.settings.columns) { j in
                            Text("\(i.value) \(j.value)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the technique of John M. to construct something Identifiable leads to a more succinct and elegant solution than mine, I would expect.