# Can't Load SwiftUI Picker Choice from Core Data and Display as Selection

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a `SwiftUI` app that persists data in `CoreData`. I want to have a Picker where
the user can choose an item (from one entity) and then store that information in
another entity to be displayed as the Picker selection.

I have an Entity named Patient where data is added by the user. I have an Entity
named Clinic that is a list of objects created by the user. The purpose is to use
the picker to rapidly add information without repeatedly typing the items for each
Patient record.

In `Swift`, I did this by attaching a UIPicker to a TextField. That worked fine. I have
not been able to do the equivalent in SwiftUI. I can make the creation and population
of the picker data and I successfully save changes to the Patient entity, but I have
not been able to load the Patient Clinic data into the picker as the default when the
Detail View is loaded.

**This piece of the app is equivalent to the master/detail style. The DetailView is:**

```
struct DetailView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Clinic.getAllClinics()) var clinics: FetchedResults<Clinic>
    @State private var selectClinicItem: Int = 0
    var patient: Patient

    @State private var updatedFirstName: String = "No First Name"
    @State private var updatedLastName: String = "No Last Name"
    @State private var updatedClinic: String = "Clinic Not Chosen"
    @State private var chosenClinicUUID: UUID = UUID()

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {
            Group {//top group
                VStack {
                    MyDataCell(tfData: $updatedFirstName, passedInLabel: "First Name", patient: patient, patientAttribute: patient.firstName ?? "No First")
                }//Top VStack - 8 views
            }//top Group

            Group {//second group
                Form {
                    Picker(selection: self.$chosenClinicUUID, label: Text("Choose Clinic")) {
                        ForEach(clinics) { c in
                            Text("\(c.name ?? "no name")")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width:320, height: 30)
                }//Form
                .frame(width:350, height: 200)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
                .padding(.leading, 12)
                .padding(.top, 20)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            }//second Group

        }//scroll or top level Form

            .modifier(AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard())
            .navigationBarTitle("View and Edit", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {

                self.patient.firstName = self.updatedFirstName
                self.patient.lastName = self.updatedLastName
                self.patient.clinicName = self.updatedClinic
                self.patient.clinicID = self.chosenClinicUUID

                let n = self.clinics.filter { $0.id == self.patient.clinicID }

                if n.count > 0 {
                    self.patient.clinicName = n[0].name
                }

                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                self.updatedFirstName = ""
                self.updatedLastName = ""
                self.updatedClinic = ""

                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

            }) {
                Text("Save")
            })

    }//body
}
```

**And for reference, the Patient class:**

```
public class Patient : NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged public var clinicName: String?
    @NSManaged public var clinicID: UUID
}

extension Patient {
    static func getAllPatients() -> NSFetchRequest<Patient> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Patient> = Patient.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Patient>
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return request
    }
}
```

**The Clinic class:**

```
public class Clinic : NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var comment: String?
    @NSManaged public var isShown: Bool
}

extension Clinic {
    static func getAllClinics() -> NSFetchRequest<Clinic> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Clinic> = Clinic.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Clinic>
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return request
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

**Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500)**

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, a dummy instance of Icon

```
  @FetchRequest(
    entity: Icon.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: []
  ) var coreDataIcon: FetchedResults<Icon>

  @State private var oneCoreDataIconIndex: Int = 0

  var body: some View {

    Form {

        Picker("Select Icon", selection: $oneCoreDataIconIndex) {
          ForEach (0..<coreDataIcon.count) {
            Image(systemName: self.coreDataIcon[$0].wrappedIcon)
              .tag($0)
              .font(.title)
          }//ForEach

        }//Picker

      }//Form
```

... later in my code, I was able to add the relationship

```
oneAccount.icon = self.coreDataIcon[self.oneCoreDataIconIndex]
```

in your case, you can do

```
    @State private var chosenClinicIndex: Int = 0
```

...and

```
       Picker(selection: $chosenClinicIndex, label: Text("Choose Clinic")) {
          ForEach(0..<clinics.count) {
            Text("\(self.clinics[$0].name ?? "no name")").tag($0)
          }
        }
```

later in your code

```
self.patient.clinicID = self.clinics[self.chosenClinicIndex].id
```

this will also show an initial clinic before you pick

like mine
[image]

Comment: This did not make a difference for me. Just to be clear, once an item is chosen in the picker, the name does show as expected - it is the initial display of the detail view where no name is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Int` (in combination with an array) and not the actual `UUID` as the selection variable. Check out [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-picker-and-read-values-from-it).

Comment: That's really restating the problem. I need to FIND the index of the array based on the unique clinic UUID - and it must be dynamic. The index can change at any time based on new records in the Clinic entity.

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe setting an `id` in the `ForEach` loop might solve the problem. ForEach loops without an id in SwiftUI are used for constant data only as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508378/6594394

Comment: My Core Data ManagedObjects conform to Identifiable.The problem is not getting a list to populate the picker, nor saving the selection to Core Data. The problem is displaying the already chosen and saved item as the picker selection. As shown in the above diagrams, the user has chosen Carbon Health as the clinic, but subsequent activation of the DetailView does not show the saved choice.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by manually setting the selected index during Init. Seems like a strange way to do it.

```
struct MyView: View {
    ...
    @ObservedObject var model = VideoDetailsModel()
    @State var selectedCategoryIndex : Int = -1

    // Init with initial model
    init(onDismiss: @escaping (VideoDetails?) -> ()) {
        self.onDismiss = onDismiss
    }

    // Init with existing model
    init(model: VideoDetailsViewModel, onDismiss: @escaping (VideoDetails?) -> ()) {
        self.model = model
    
        self.onDismiss = onDismiss
        let selectedIndex = self.model.categories.categories.firstIndex(where: {
            return $0 == self.model.videoModel?.categories[0]
        }) ?? -1
        
        // Force the set state here since initialisation is optional
        _selectedCategoryIndex = .init(initialValue: selectedIndex)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
    ... 
            Picker(selection: $selectedCategoryIndex , label: Text("Category")) {
                ForEach(0..<self.model.categories.categories.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(self.model.categories.categories[index])
                }
            }
    ... 
}
```